# c# Ask to save changes before selecting another item in listbox

Tags: c#, database, winforms, listbox

I'd like to integrate an autocheck that prevent user to forget to save changes with a textbox 'Do you want to save change' Yes-No

If yes - > save
if no - > returns

Here's my code without the checking

```
namespace WindowsFormsApp1
{
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    OleDbConnection conn;

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        conn = new 
        OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OleDb.4.0;Data 
        Source=" + @Application.StartupPath + "\\Database1.mdb");
        fill_lb();
    }
    private void fill_lb()
    {
        listBox1.Items.Clear();
        if (conn.State != ConnectionState.Open) { conn.Close(); 
        conn.Open(); }
        OleDbCommand cmd = conn.CreateCommand();
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
        cmd.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM [table1] ORDER BY firstn";
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        OleDbDataAdapter da = new OleDbDataAdapter(cmd);
        da.Fill(dt);
        foreach (DataRow dr in dt.Rows)
        {
            listBox1.Items.Add(dr["firstn"].ToString());
        }
        conn.Close();
    }
    private void listBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, 
    EventArgs e)
    {
        textBox_fn.Text = string.Empty;
        textBox_ln.Text = string.Empty;

        if (conn.State != ConnectionState.Open) { conn.Close(); 
        conn.Open(); }
        OleDbCommand cmd = conn.CreateCommand();
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
        cmd.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM [table1] WHERE firstn='" + 
        listBox1.SelectedItem.ToString() + "'";
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        OleDbDataAdapter da = new OleDbDataAdapter(cmd);
        da.Fill(dt);

        foreach (DataRow dr in dt.Rows)
        {
            textBox_fn.Text = dr["firstn"].ToString();
            textBox_ln.Text = dr["lastn"].ToString();
        }
        conn.Close();
    }

    private void button_savenew_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (conn.State != ConnectionState.Open) { conn.Close(); 
        conn.Open(); }
        OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand();
        cmd.Connection = conn;
        cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO [table1] ([firstn],[lastn]) 
        values ([@firstn],[@lastn])";

        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@firstn", textBox_fn.Text);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@lastn", textBox_ln.Text);
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        fill_lb();
        conn.Close();
    }

    private void button_modify_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (conn.State != ConnectionState.Open) { conn.Close(); 
        conn.Open(); }
        OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand();
        cmd.Connection = conn;
        cmd.CommandText = "UPDATE [Table1] SET [firstn]=[@firstn], 
        [lastn]=[@lastn] WHERE firstn = '" + 
        listBox1.SelectedItem.ToString() + "'";
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@firstn", textBox_fn.Text);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@lastn", textBox_ln.Text);
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        fill_lb();
        conn.Close();
    }

    private void button_new_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        textBox_fn.Text = string.Empty;
        textBox_ln.Text = string.Empty;
    }
  }
}
```

What I've done with no success :

```
    Bool modified = false

    private void  textBox_fn_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        modified = true;
    }

    private void textBox_ln_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        modified = true;
    }


    private void listBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, 
    EventArgs e)
    {
        if (modified.Equals(true))
        {
            DialogResult dialogr = MessageBox.Show("Do you want to 
            save change ?","", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo);
            switch (dialogr)
            {
                case DialogResult.Yes:
                    button_savenew.PerformClick();
                    modifie = false;
                    break;
                case DialogResult.No:
                    return;
            }
        }

        modified = false;
        textBox_fn.Text = string.Empty;
        textBox_ln.Text = string.Empty;

    }
```

This is not working because it ask to save everytime I click on listbox

What Can I do ?

Comment: Maybe you should perform the check in the `OnClosing` event of the form and not in the `SelectedIndexChanged` of the list

Comment: yes I could add a check at OnClosing but , If I am editing an entry and I miss click on another one from listbox , I 'd like to perform that check too.

Answer (score 2):

I would look into using a [MessageBox](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.messagebox?view=netframework-4.7.2). It would greatly simplify what you are trying to do. Perform the check in the background, and if they didn't save do this:

```
        string message = "Are you sure you don't want to save?";
                       string caption = "Error Detected in Input";
        MessageBoxButtons buttons = MessageBoxButtons.YesNo;
        DialogResult result;

        // Displays the MessageBox.

        result = MessageBox.Show(message, "Are you Sure", buttons);

        if (result == System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.Yes)
        {

            // Save file

        }
        if (result == System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.No){
            this.Close();
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove the the associate code from `listBox1_SelectedIndexChanged` event and add to it the end of `button_modify_Click`. Try like:

```
private  void Check()
{
      if (modified.Equals(true))
        {
            DialogResult dialogr = MessageBox.Show("Do you want to 
            save change ?","", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo);
            switch (dialogr)
            {
                case DialogResult.Yes:
                    button_savenew.PerformClick();
                    modifie = false;
                    break;
                case DialogResult.No:
                    return;
            }
        }

        modified = false;
        textBox_fn.Text = string.Empty;
        textBox_ln.Text = string.Empty;
}

 private void button_modify_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
        if (conn.State != ConnectionState.Open) { conn.Close(); 
        conn.Open(); }
        OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand();
        cmd.Connection = conn;
        cmd.CommandText = "UPDATE [Table1] SET [firstn]=[@firstn], 
        [lastn]=[@lastn] WHERE firstn = '" + 
        listBox1.SelectedItem.ToString() + "'";
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@firstn", textBox_fn.Text);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@lastn", textBox_ln.Text);
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        fill_lb();
        Check(); //<--added here
        conn.Close();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try resetting `modified` after DB update, at the end of `button_modify_Click`

Answer (score 0):

I think I found the right way to do the job using the tag property.

first I add a new boolean that will check if I leave a textbox

```
  bool left_txtbox = false; //when leaving textbox
```

then I add this code the the Leave property of textboxes

```
 private void textBox_fn_Leave(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        name = listBox1.SelectedItem.ToString();
        textBox_fn.Tag = textBox_fn.Text;
        left_txtbox = true;
    }

    private void textBox_ln_Leave(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        name = listBox1.SelectedItem.ToString();
        textBox_ln.Tag = textBox_ln.Text;
        left_txtbox = true;
    }
```

on listbox selected index change I add the check when leaving textbox

```
private void listBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (left_txtbox == true) Check(); // if txtbox has been left, do the check
        textBox_fn.Text = string.Empty;
        textBox_ln.Text = string.Empty;

        if (conn.State != ConnectionState.Open) { conn.Close(); conn.Open(); }
        OleDbCommand cmd = conn.CreateCommand();
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
        cmd.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM [table1] WHERE firstn='" + listBox1.SelectedItem.ToString() + "'";
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        OleDbDataAdapter da = new OleDbDataAdapter(cmd);
        da.Fill(dt);

        foreach (DataRow dr in dt.Rows)
        {
            textBox_fn.Text = dr["firstn"].ToString();
            textBox_ln.Text = dr["lastn"].ToString();
        }


        conn.Close();
    }
```

finally the check itself, it will compare the Tag with the value stored in DB

```
 private void Check()
    {

        if (conn.State != ConnectionState.Open) { conn.Close(); conn.Open(); }
        OleDbCommand cmd = conn.CreateCommand();
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
        cmd.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM [table1] WHERE firstn='" + name + "'";
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        OleDbDataAdapter da = new OleDbDataAdapter(cmd);
        da.Fill(dt);

        foreach (DataRow dr in dt.Rows)
        {
            try // ignore null values
            {

                if (textBox_fn.Tag.ToString() != dr["firstn"].ToString()) { modified = true; }
                if (textBox_ln.Tag.ToString() != dr["lastn"].ToString()) { modified = true; }
            }
            catch { }

        if (modified.Equals(true))
        {
            DialogResult dialogr = MessageBox.Show("Do you want to save change ? ", "", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo);
            switch (dialogr)
            {
                case DialogResult.Yes:
                    button_savenew.PerformClick();
                    modified = false;
                    break;
                case DialogResult.No:
                    modified = false;
                    return;
            }
        }

        modified = false;

    }
```

I think the code can be optimized